# How can I link react js page into my html website?

Tags: reactjs

```html
 <div class="edit-button">
                      <a href="http://localhost:3000/">
                      <button class="ed-button" type="button"><span class="edit-s"></span><i class="uil uil-edit-alt"></i> Edit</button>
                    </a>
                    </div>
```

**I created a react app page that can configure the paint of a house model and i want to know how can i link that page into my html website without using npm start, all I could do is this which i can only link to localhost.**

Comment: Please create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). No one can help you based on the information you've provided.